# jQuery Clone Problems

Tags: jquery, clone

Here is my scenario:

```
<div class="item">
<div class="item-title">
<a href="_files/download_item.zip" class="link">Download 1</a>
</div>
<div class="item-description"> Lorem ipsum dolor…. </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to clone the anchor and append it to the "item-description" div.

The problem is when I have multiple items that the clone function then copies ALL of the anchors to ALL of the "item-description" divs.

Here is the jquery I am using:

```
$(function(){   
    $('a.link').clone(true).appendTo('.item-description');
});
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $("a.link").each(function(){
    $(this).clone(true).appendTo($(this).parent().siblings(".item-description"));
  });
});
```

Comment: I think this is what he want... copy the corresponding `.link` to its `.item-description`

Comment: BINGO! ... That did it! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){   
    var links = $('.item-title a.link');
    links.each(function() {
       $(this).parent().next('.item-description').append($(this).clone(true));
    });
});
```

Comment: This won't work since it will clone the first `a` and then append it to _every_ `.item-description` div.

Comment: That copies the FIRST items link to all the subsequent items. I need to copy each items link to that particular items description.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $(".item").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".item-description")
            .append($(this).find("a.link").clone(true));
    });
});
```

Comment: I think `$(".item-title").each` should be `$(".item").each`